# Iterate through same class and set countdown

Tags: jquery

I want to setup a countdown timer for multiple elements with the same class called ".countdown", but for some reason, .html() doesn't show the countdown inside these elements.

HTML:

```
<div>
<div class="expiry">2021-12-10 11:12:50</div>
<div class="countdown"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="expiry">2022-09-12 07:27:34</div>
<div class="countdown"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".expiry").each(function () {

        var expiry = $(this).text();

        var x = setInterval(function () {
            
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            
            var distance = expiry - now;

            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            $(this).closest("div").find(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

        }, 1000);

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save reference of current div which is been iterated outside `setInterval` and use it inside i.e : `selector.next()..`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".expiry").each(function() {

  var expiry = new Date($(this).text()); //use date...
  var selector = $(this) //save refernce

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = expiry - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    //use next
    selector.next(".countdown").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="expiry">2021-12-10 11:12:50</div>
  <div class="countdown"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="expiry">2022-09-12 07:27:34</div>
  <div class="countdown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works fine. But why can't I use $(this) inside the setInterval() to reference to the ".expiry" class?

Meanwhile I also found another working solution by adding "index" and "item" paramenter into the function => $(".repost_datetime").each(function (index, item) { ... }); and using $(item) instead of $(this). Is this also a right approach?